# Need some help for swift substring

Tags: swift

```
var t = "13,45,344"
print(t.prefix(upTo: t.firstIndex(of: ",")))
```

results in  error: value of optional type 'String.Index?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String.Index'
print(t.prefix(upTo: t.firstIndex(of: ",")))

SWIFT makes me crazy

Comment: What result do you want if there is no comma? Remember, `firstIndex` returns an optional because the substring may not exist in the string.

Comment: If dealing with optionals drives you crazy...you're gonna have to get used to that. They're there to force you to deal with potential invalid input, rather than get unexpected crashes down the line when something happens that you didn't account for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the behavior you want when there is no comma. I assume you would like to print the whole thing. In that case you don't need indexes at all. You want "prefix as long as the current character is not comma:"

```
print(t.prefix(while: { $0 != "," }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimal no crashing version of your code with supporting for **NO COMMA** situation:

```
if let prefix = t.firstIndex(of: ",") {
    print(t.prefix(upTo: prefix))
} else {
    print(t)
}
```

Or even more simpler mentioned by [@rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy):

```
print(t.prefix(upTo: t.firstIndex(of: ",") ?? t.endIndex))
```

Comment: Or simply `print(t.prefix(upTo: t.firstIndex(of: ",") ?? t.endIndex))`

Comment: very wise @rmaddy